# echo, var_dump() and print_r() interrupts output

Tags: php, zend-framework, echo, mamp, var-dump

I'm trying to configure php/mysql on Mac (via MAMP) and strange problem occurs.

The project uses Zend Framework 2 and I'm trying to debug it simply putting var_dump();

If I do this only var_dump() renders but no web site content.

Same branch and commit on Windows configured enviroment (WAMP Server) — no problem: var_dump() renders along with website templates.

Same happens to echo and print_r.

It seem to be a very simple problem in php.ini config or smth. but I didn't find it googling "var_dump interrupts output", "var_dump no website content", etc.

PS
No errors/warnings in php log files.

Comment: This is because most frameworks like ZF expect your controllers simply to pass information to the template engine, and the templating does all the output (including headers); echoing output directly within controllers or models breaks that MVC pattern, sending its output before the headers are sent, and will cause problems

Comment: @MarkBaker this is the answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: check `php.ini` settings for `output_buffering` and `implicit_flush`.

Comment: Depending on how you use ZF2, your output will only be 'rendered' at the very end of the application logic, and instant-output functions/language constructs like the one you mentioned will interfere with headers the framework is likely sending before the content. You should have a _'Headers already sent'_ error somewhere in that case, though. Double-check your php.ini directives?

Comment: @pinkgothic I understand MVC. But it works on my windows machine and that's what make me a little crazy. Same source code, so must be some config thing. But what exactly? No 'Headers already sent' errors. ERR_ALL is enabled

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks. Checked those and made them on however nothing's changed. I even searched for 'output' and found nothing more that could help me in php.ini config. Could be there an option that's not in config but I should use it? I'll try to diff my Mac's php.ini with Win's one.